# 7-zip - Splitting archive on multiple disks can't extract directly?

Tags: dvd, 7-zip

So I basically want to back up some things that require me to have a split archive on multiple DVDs. The problem is that 7-Zip gives me an "Unexpected end of data" error unless all the parts are in the same folder. The best solution I've been able to think of is to cobble together a batch file or a small c++ program to copy the files to a temp folder, but this solution is less than elegant. Basically, the way I want it to work is that when it's done with one of the split files, it asks for the next file. Is there any easier way to go about this than what I came up with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of beginning of 2017, `7zip` can't extract files from single split 7z archive, to be able to extract your files, you will need all archive's parts.

`7zip` can do such thing you want with `ISO` images tho.

```
7z x archive.iso.003 -tiso.split -o extraction_directory
```